# How do I reset a disk to non-RAID?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, sata

I had a couple SATA hard disks in a RAID 1 array. I reset them to non-RAID in the Intel raid manager, and removed one drive.

Despite the raid controller saying it's *not* a RAID disk, and even disabling RAID from the BIOS setup, it still appears as a RAID disk in the boot menu (pictured).

[image: old RAID disk still shows as RAID]

In its current state, I am unable to install Windows on it as windows setup is not able to create a partition. How do I totally reset it to a non-RAID disk?

Comment: It's not telling you that it's a RAID disk. It's telling you the disk is connected to the RAID **controller**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have the set the "Disk Controller" (or similar) in your BIOS to RAID (usual options are IDE, SATA, RAID). Change it back to SATA. **Note** that this will no longer invoke the Intel RAID Manager on boot.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I had only disabled the *extra* RAID controller. I also needed to set the RAID mode to IDE instead of RAID in the "On-Chip ATA Devices" submenu.

Comment: +1 this is absolutly what I was starting to type as answer.