# Cannot read error in console nor via redirect

Tags: linux, terminal, redirection, console, ubuntu-20.04

What I have done:  Installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.6LTS to SSD (/sda), extra drives HDD (/sdb).  There is an extra HDD (call it /sdc for now) that was RAID1.

RAID1:  I followed the ideas outlined [here, to reset the RAID1](https://superuser.com/questions/444071/how-do-i-reset-a-disk-to-non-raid) and [here, to change the RAID1 device](https://www.dell.com/community/Storage-Drives-Media/RAID-Free-Changing-from-RAID1-to-non-RAID/td-p/2482135)

What is happening.  I am using the command `sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /'` to  list the details of connected drives.  As long as /sdc is not connected everything works as expected.

Once /sdc is connected a error message that scrolls off the terminal window appears in the middle of the report on screen.

I have tried `Shift + PgUp` and `Shift + PgDown`.  I have tried  `Shift + A` then `Esc` and scroll does not happen.

I have tried `sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /'  >001stdout.txt 2>002stderr.txt` and the error is not being captured to the file.

I have tried [these suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file) and [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487133/how-to-save-the-contents-of-unlogged-console-screen-to-a-file) and [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1734501/modify-21-so-that-output-goes-to-a-specific-file-and-any-errors-or-other-outpu) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448711/see-everything-in-the-terminal-command-prompt-after-long-output) to no avail.

I would prefer not to use Screen and tmux if possible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it is actually coming from fdisk in the first place. When working at the text console, you can have *kernel* messages intermixed with program output – they are neither stdout nor stderr of the command being run but a completely separate source of messages.

Any console message starting with a `[   12345.678]` style timestamp **is a kernel message.** The most recent messages can be viewed using `dmesg`, though they all are usually captured in your system logs (journal or syslog) as well.

> I have tried `sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /'  >001stdout.txt 2>002stderr.txt` and the error is not being captured to the file.

This didn't work because you're not redirecting the stderr of fdisk – you're only redirecting the stderr **of 'grep'** (which doesn't produce anything to stderr anyway). The pipe `|` only connects fdisk's stdout but does nothing to its stderr<sup>1</sup>, which continues to go directly to the terminal.

To capture the stderr of fdisk, place the redirection **next to it:**

```
sudo fdisk -l 2>fdisk_stderr.txt | grep 'Disk /'
```

In order to apply redirection to a whole pipeline, you would need to group the commands:

```
(sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /') >001stdout.txt 2>002stderr.txt
-or-
{ sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /'; } >001stdout.txt 2>002stderr.txt
```

<sup>1</sup> In other cases you could cause both stdout and stderr to be piped together, using either of:

```
sudo fdisk -l 2>&1 | grep ... >stdout 2>stderr
-or-
sudo fdisk -l |& grep ... >stdout 2>stderr
```

but this method won't really work here, as your `grep` would filter the error message away.

Comment: This is a great insight and the code worked well.

Comment: `lsbkl -e7` has an excellent human readable layout of the mounted devices.  Though in my case _/sdc_ was returning far too many I/O errors.  So I have replaced the drive.

Also check out [viewing logs (2022)](https://sematext.com/blog/ubuntu-logs/) and [here as well (2023)](https://www.makeuseof.com/ubuntu-error-logs-guide/)